# Declaring global variables in Java

Tags: java, applet

I am making an online test web project using applets. I want to declare a variable of `int` type which keeps track of number of correct answers. So where is that variable required to be declared so that it can be accessed in all the frames?

Comment: What about to create one class with only all parameters ? And use it as/by reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have mentioned, you can declare a global variable using `public static`:

```
public class MyClass {

    public static int globallyVisibleInt = ...;

    // or

    private static int visibleThroughAccessors = ...;

    public static void messWithGlobalState(int newValue) {
        visibleThroughAccessors = newValue;
    }

    public static int seeGlobalState() {
        return visibleThroughAccessors;
    }

}
```

Then to access and use this variable, any other code would merely have to import this class:

```
// this code is inside another class and package
MyClass.globallyVisibleInt++;

// or
MyClass.messWithGlobalState(14);
```

However, **this use of global variables is generally frowned upon.** OOP gives you lots of tools for dealing with problems, and you probably don't need global variables for this specific case.

---

[Here's](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad) a good piece about avoiding global variables -- why and how.  Discussion:

> As with all HeuristicRules, this is not a rule that applies 100% of the time. Code is generally clearer and easier to maintain when it does not use globals, but there are exceptions. It is similar in spirit to GotoConsideredHarmful, although use of global variables is less likely to get you branded as an inveterate hacker.

**Why Global Variables Should Be Avoided When Unnecessary:**

- Non-locality
- No Access Control or Constraint Checking
- Implicit coupling
- Concurrency issues
- Testing and Confinement

**Alternatives to Global Variables:**

- ContextObject
- Stateful Procedures
- Singleton Pattern
- Hidden Globals

Comment: @Lion -- I'm not sure what exactly you're proposing.

Answer (score 1):

There is no global variables in java. You can declare public static field in some class or private static field with public static accessors

Comment: i know there is no global  variable in java . will declaring it static give us the freedom to access it in different frames under same package

Answer (score 1):

In [OOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) there are no global variables, but you can declare a public static variable. But this is no good practice! You should investigate how to handle it in your case and find another way.

Comment: OOP has no global variables because it is not a language.  Even Java (for example) has no global variables in the C / FORTRAN sense.  Statics have to be qualified by the name of the enclosing class at some point.  A C or FORTRAN global is truly global, and that's one of the things that makes them dangerous.